# Zend framework 2 - How to bind form data with a simple array

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm looking for clean solution how to bind form data with array only?
I was trying to convert in to stdClass object with no result.

Form

```
class Product extends Form
{

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct('add_product');

    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'type',
        'type' => 'Select',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Product type:',
            'value_options' => $this->getProductTypeCollection(),
            //'empty_option' => '',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => 'simple',
            'class' => 'select'
        )
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'set',
        'type' => 'Select',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Product attribute set:',
            'value_options' => $this->getAttributeSetCollection(),
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'select'
        )
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'categories',
        'type' => 'MultiCheckbox',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Categories:',
            'value_options' => $this->getCategoryTree(),
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'multi-checkbox'
        )
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'websites',
        'type' => 'Text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Website:',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'text',
            'readonly' => 'readonly',
            'value' => $session->magento_store_view_code,
        )
    ));
  }
}
```

In edit action:

```
$form = new ProductForm();
$form->bind($productData);
```

$productData is an array and it looks like this:

```
array (size=52)
    'product_id' => string '6' (length=1)
    'sku' => string '10/10/1992' (length=10)
    'set' => string '4' (length=1)
    'type' => string 'simple' (length=6)
    'categories' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3' (length=1)
    'websites' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1' (length=1)
    'type_id' => string 'simple' (length=6)
    'name' => string 'Front fog lights set crystal smoked VW Golf MK2, Jetta MK2' (length=58)
    'description' => string 'Front fog lights set crystal smoked VW Golf MK2, Jetta MK2' (length=58)
    'short_description' => string 'Front fog lights set crystal smoked VW Golf MK2, Jetta MK2' (length=58)
    'weight' => string '2.0000' (length=6)
    'old_id' => null
    'news_from_date' => null
    'news_to_date' => null
    'status' => string '1' (length=1)
    'url_key' => string 'front-fog-lights-set-crystal-smoked-vw-golf-mk2-jetta-mk2' (length=57)
    'url_path' => string 'front-fog-lights-set-crystal-smoked-vw-golf-mk2-jetta-mk2.html' (length=62)
    'visibility' => string '4' (length=1)
    'category_ids' => 
            array (size=1)
                    0 => string '3' (length=1)
    'required_options' => string '0' (length=1)
    'price' => string '49.9900' (length=7)
    ...
```

Regards,

Comment: Give us your form, give us your array, tell us what didn't work, tell us what you expect to work... don't let us do the work for you...

Comment: Hope that this information will be much more useful.

Comment: Use bindValues($array) and i think you should use bind($object) $object here should be your stdClass, also maybe you will need to setHydrator() on your Product form. I didnt do it this way with stdClass so im not 100% sure.

Comment: Thx. Well I got it like this:

$product = new Product();
$product->exchangeArray($productInfo);
            
$form = new ProductForm();
$form->bind($product);

I'm getting product entity then I'm using exchangeArray method and I'm passing product object to form :)

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
        $form = new ProductForm();
        $form->bind($productData);
```

to this

```
      $product = new Product(); 
      $product->exchangeArray(get_object_vars($productData));
      $form=new ProductForm();
      $form->bind($product);   
      $form->get('submit')->setValue('Save');
```